# How large is too large a capacitance across SMPS?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inrush-current

I have a circuit that operates from a 16 VAC input from a transformer. For the purposes of this question, just consider it to be a linear power supply: AC -> full wave bridge rectifier -> large electrolytic caps for filtering -> a few stages of common-collector transistors. It all works fine.

But I'd like it to work also if somebody would rather plug a DC source into it.

Testing it myself with a DC input, it works fine. The DC goes through the bridge rectifier, and other than the diode drops (which are not a concern), all is well.

But what if somebody uses an SMPS, like a laptop charger? These are cheap and commonly available in 16 VDC. My concern is that I have about 16000 μF of filter capacitors on the input, and I know that SMPS start-up can automatically shut down if it sees too large an inrush current.

Is 16000 μF "large" or troublesome for an SMPS running at 16 V with a current capacity of about 3 A?

Comment: 16mF is a **ton** of capacitance, so almost certainly yes. The inrush current as the caps charge is likely to be extremely high. You can maybe resolve this with a metal oxide varistor (MOV) on the input.

Comment: Too large depends on power supply specifications and if for a random power supply it is unknown, and 16mF is typically a very high amount of capacitance on a switch mode supply output. The real question is, how do you know 16mF is not too large for your AC input as well? High capacitance will reduce conduction angle and increase peak current, so unless the high capacitance is actually needed, it's not a good idea to have a lot of capacitance.

Comment: @Polynomial, i think you meant a NTC thermistor rather than a varistor.  you would normally use some form of soft start. A NTC thermistor is ine solution, a resistor along with a time delay relay or voltage sense so that the resistor charges that capacitor after some time or a voltage is reached, then relay bypas ses the resistor. You can also use mosfets or bjts. Another technique is a pem ramp that slowly increases the on time until 100%

Comment: To answer some questions, first, I have the large capacitance in there because in "analog" mode, where this thing is driven from a simple AC transformer (or AC wall wart), I still want to keep ripple down, with minimal wasted power and heat - hence, no internal linear regulator.  It's okay if the output voltage drops a little under load.  As to whether 16000uF is too much, I guess I don't "know" that, other than to say that the caps don't get the least bit warm, nor does the AC power transformer.

Comment: I conducted an experiment.  I took every DC switcher wall wart I had in my stash and hooked it up to 20,000uF of capacitance (two 10,000 caps in parallel).  Every one of them, from a nice Apple "iHome" brick to the cheapest no-name ones from China, came right up without a hitch.  So overcurrent protection or soft-start capability, must be a pretty common thing, at least in switcher wall adapters.

Comment: @Kartman Yeah, you're right, I'm not sure why I said a MOV.

Comment: Another data point.  I got a 3.75A 16VDC laptop charger (a switcher) and tested with that.  Same result.  I can slap 20,000uF across it, plug it in, and it charges right up and sits at 16V no problem.  These tests are not convincing me that I need to worry about this.  Something perhaps we are not considering is that while a 20,000uF cap could cause an inrush of anywhere from 100-180 amp (depending on the cap specs), that will be severely limited by simple things like the wiring, transformer windings, and other internal resistances of the charger.